# Test whether a function was invoked without mocking

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, specs2

Suppose I have a function `def bar(y: Int, f: Int => Int): Int`. Now I would like to test `bar` using `specs2` and make sure `f` is invoked.

How to do it *functionally* without mutable vars. Can I do it without *mocks* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var called = false
bar(1, i => { called = true; i + 1 })
assert(called)
```

**Edit:**

> How to do it functionally?

Assuming `bar` is pure:

```
val bar1 = bar(1, i => 0)
val bar2 = bar(1, i => 1)
assert(bar1 != bar2)
```

But if `bar` is impure or if it's not using the result of `f` in it's output, it's impossible to test for the invocation of `f` in functional way. Indeed, by definition of purity, there is be no observable differences between invoking and now invoking a pure function.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer doing _functional_ way without mutable variables though. I will update the question.

Comment: In fact `bar` could still be pure and this test is not guaranteed to work: `def bar(y: Int, f: Int => Int) = if (f(y) < 0) -1 else 1`. I don't think it's possible without mutation, unless maybe if you have more information about what `bar` is supposed to do.

Comment: Of course that depends on the implementation, who writes tests without access to the code being tested??